# Will this converstion to/from fixed point cause me to lose precision?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a situation where I have a fixed point number that I want to convert to and from a floating point number.  Specifically it is the `SANE_Fixed` type from the [SANE API](http://www.sane-project.org/html/doc011.html#s4.2).  Here is the what the documentation says (I grabbed the bits I think are relavant):

> SANE_Fixed is used for variables that can take fixed point values in the range -32768 to 32767.9999 with a resolution of 1/65535.
>
> ```
> #define SANE_FIXED_SCALE_SHIFT  16 
> typedef SANE_Word SANE_Fixed;
> ```
>
> The macro SANE_FIXED_SCALE_SHIFT gives the location of the fixed binary
>   point. This standard defines that value to be 16, which yields a
>   resolution of 1/65536.
>
> SANE_Word: A word is encoded as 4 bytes (32
>   bits). The bytes are ordered from most-significant to
>   least-significant byte (big-endian byte-order).

So, over the wire I get 4 bytes which I convert into a .Net `int` like this (you can guess what `GetByte` and `SendByte` do):

```
public int GetWord()
{
    int value = 0;
    value += (GetByte() << 24);
    value += (GetByte() << 16);
    value += (GetByte() << 8);
    value += (GetByte() << 0);
    return value;
}
```

Then I want to convert that `int` into a floating point number (I went for `decimal`) like this:

```
public decimal ToFloating(int source)
{
    decimal value = source / ((decimal)(1 << 16));
    return value;
}
```

And I will also need to go back the other way so I would convert to fixed like this:

```
public int ToFixed(decimal source)
{
    decimal value = source * ((decimal)(1 << 16));
    return (int)value;
}
```

And then convert to four bytes like this to send it like so:

```
public void SendWord(int word)
{
    SendByte((word >> 24) & 0xff);
    SendByte((word >> 16) & 0xff);
    SendByte((word >> 8) & 0xff);
    SendByte((word >> 0) & 0xff);
}
```

So, here is my question:

This seems a pretty simplistic implementation to me and I read lots of stuff on the internet about creating custom fixed point classes and whatnot but, given the constraints of my scenario, is this a safe approach to take?  Could I lose precision and is the maths correct?

Comment: Have you tried it? Does it seem to work?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it and it does seem to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `SANE_Fixed` type has a constantly fixed precision of 1/65536, that means it always stores the fractional part of the number as a 16 bit (two-byte) unsigned integer (hence the `SANE_FIXED_SCALE_SHIFT` of 16 bits).  Since the whole number portion of the value can range from -32768 to 32767, that means that the whole part of the number is represented with a 16 bit signed integer (making the type use a total of 4 bytes).

The `decimal` type in .NET, while it is a floating point type, it is far more precise that the traditional `float` type.  It stores a 96 bit integer (plus an additional bit for the sign).  It then stores the position of the decimal point as a 5-bit integer, which allows the decimal point to be located after any digit in the 96-bit integer value.  As such, the larger the value gets, the lower the fractional precision becomes.

In other words, the `decimal` type can store a value up to 79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335 (29 digits).  If it does store a 29 digit number, however, it will be unable to store any fractional value with that.  It will only store the whole part of the number.  If, however, it is only storing a single digit value, the fractional part can be up to 28 digits long (e.g. 0.0000000000000000000000000001).

Bearing all of that in mind, if the maximum whole number that the `SANE_Fixed` type can store is 32767 (a five digit number), when cast to a `decimal` type, that leaves 24 digits of precision (e.g. 1/10^24) in the fractional part of the number.  That is still *far* more precise than the 1/65536 precision provided by the `SANE_Fixed` type.

Therefore, you can be confident that the `decimal` type will accurately retain the precise value.  Obviously, when casting from a `decimal` back into a `SANE_Fixed` type, you will lose precision, but since the value came from that type in the first place, your values are safe.